# SQL Server Backup Set "Description"

Tags: sql-server, backup

When manually backing up a database in SQL Server 2008, there is an area to enter a Description for the backup set (below Name)

But how do I review the description when restoring a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way of getting it to show up in the UI. It seems to be viewable in the `msdb.dbo.backupset` table.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I needed.  Very odd that you can enter it through the UI but it doesn't seem to display anywhere in the UI though.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to read the description from a backup created on a different server, you can't use the `backupset` table.  Instead, use:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\myfile.bak'
```

The `BackupDescription` column will contain the description:

[image]

Comment: how can i find the BackupDescription ?

Comment: @motevalizadeh it is one of the columns returned by [`RESTORE HEADERONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)